# Viewing web app logs stored in Azure blob storage

Tags: azure, logging, azure-blob-storage

I have created a .Net Core 1.1 web app and hosted it in Azure with the logging concepts covered briefly in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/10/25/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1-preview-1/

I have then setup logs to write to an Azure blob storage which I can see working, however from what I can see, the only way to actually view these logs are by downloading individual files.

Is there a way to see all of these logs in a stream with date filtering etc or how to feed that data into a different Azure application that could provide a usable GUI like Kibana?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to see all of these logs in a stream with date filtering etc or how to feed that data into a different Azure application that could provide a usable GUI like Kibana?

The log file is grouped by date. If you want to view the log online, you could install a web site extension named [Azure Web Site Logs Browser](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/websitelogs/) which could allow us to view all the logs(from blobs service and file system). You can also fork this project from [GitHub](https://github.com/amitapl/ThatLogExtension) and apply your own query on logs.

[image]

Steps to add Azure Web Site Logs Browser extension.

Azure portal -> Open your Web App -> Choose [Extensions] menu-> Click [Add] link-> Choose the extension you want to add.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have enabled 'Application logging' under 'App service -> Diagnostics logs', you will be able to view real-time log information under 'App server -> Log Stream'.

For GUI filtering capabilities, checkout Azure OMS Log Analytics. It can do comprehensive log filtering and analytics.

For application specific details, you can check 'Application Insights'.

Hope that helps, 
Mihir

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a desktop application to show the contents of various Azure storage containers. It is called the [Azure Storage Explorer](http://storageexplorer.com/)